# How to add two edges having the same label (but different endpoints) in JUNG?

Tags: java, swing, jung, visualizer

How to add two edges having the same label but different endpoints?

For example, I want to add two edges having the same label 'label1', one from vertex v-1 to vertex v-2 and the other one from vertex v-2 to v-3.

Part of the code would be:

```
g.addEdge("label1","v-1","v-2");
g.addEdge("label1","v-2","v-3");
```

But JUNG does not allow to add two edges with the same label. It gives an error:

> edge label1 already exists in this graph with endpoints [v-1, v-2] and cannot
>   be added with endpoints [v-2, v-3]

How can I add two edges having the same label?

Thanks.

## Edit:

I just read that there is a way to assign a weight value to an edge, that is by using [EdgeWeightLabeller](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/jung/jung/1.7.6/jung-1.7.6-javadoc.jar!/doc/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/decorators/EdgeWeightLabeller.html), but these weight values should be integers. So it does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add a space to the second edge? `"label1 "`

Comment: Thank You Joop Eggen. That is really a good idea! It solves the problem for two edges, which is what I have asked here :) But I asked for two edges for the sake of simplicity. Actually I'll get many such edges. So I do not know how my graph will look like if I add a space for each such edge label. Anyway thank you again for your idea.

Comment: Searching a vertex or an edge will be difficult just by its name. What happens if you want more than two vertices with the same label name? Would you append more spaces? I don't think so. How about you define a custom Java class (user data) that contains a few fields; one field for a unique id and one field for its name; apply this class as the generic vertex part (you can do the same for the generic edge part but with another custom class). Use `vertexLabelTransformer()` to displays the name part of the class instance, but use the unique id for searching, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are not required to be the toString() of the edges; that's just the default.  Take a look at PluggableRendererContext to see how to supply a Transformer that provides a property for each element of the graph.

I'd also check out the section in the JUNG 2 manual (on the wiki) that talks about user data: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/jung/wiki/JUNGManual#UserData

Comment: Thank you Joshua! I am glad that there exists a method. I am still learning about these transformers. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem, I make my label String (your is already a String) and make its value like this: "ID_OF_FIRST_VERTEX:ID_OF_SECOND_VERTEX:EDGE_VALUE". Then, to display just a value, I do use transformation. Its simple, it just takes the edge_value from name of edge.

In this sample I use a separator ":".

```
VisualizationViewer vv = new VisualizationViewer(layout, dim);
//other operations
vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new Transformer<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String transform(String c) {
        return StringUtils.substringAfterLast(c, ":");
    }
});
```

Of course you dont have to use StringUtils from Apache Commons, a normal String.subString will work here as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;


public class JungNetwork {

public static Graph<String, String> getGraph() 
{
    Graph<String, String> g = new DirectedSparseMultigraph<String, String>();

    g.addVertex("v1");
    g.addVertex("v2");
    g.addVertex("v3");
    g.addEdge("label1", "v1", "v2");
    g.addEdge("label2", "v2", "v3");
    g.addEdge("label3", "v3", "v1");
    return g;
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    final Graph<String, String> g = getGraph();
    VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv =    new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(new FRLayout<String, String>(g));

    final Transformer <String, String> edgeLabel = new Transformer<String, String>(){

        @Override
        public String transform(String edge) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (edge.equals("label1")|| edge.equals("label2")){
                return "label1";
            }else
            return "label3";
        }

    };


    vv.getRenderContext().setLabelOffset(15);
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(edgeLabel);

    f.getContentPane().add(vv);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

The Result:

[image]