# Jung how to display vertex label from net file quato

Tags: label, vertex, jung

i have a net file like this:

```
1 "assurance"
2 "regime"
3 "Cambodia"
4 "talks"
5 "freedom"
6 ""
7 "November"
8 "October"
9 "the_opposition"
10 "political"
...
```

i made a graph but this graph doesn't display words in " "
what should i do to show vertex label ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288886/vertex-label-in-jung-graph-visualization

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer

```
PajekNetReader<Graph<Number, Number>, Number, Number> pnr = 
    new PajekNetReader<Graph<Number, Number>, Number,Number>(
        vertexFactory, edgeFactory);
final Graph<Number,Number> graph = new SparseMultigraph<Number, Number>();
pnr.load(br, graph);
final AggregateLayout<Number,Number> layout = 
    new AggregateLayout<Number,Number>(new FRLayout<Number,Number>(graph));

vv = new VisualizationViewer<Number,Number>(layout);
vv.setBackground( Color.white );
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(pnr.getVertexLabeller());
```